# Prevent rasterio to read nodata value as nan?

Tags: python, rasterio, numpy

When reading a raster dataset with rasterio 1.3.3, nodata values are replaced by `nan`.

How to read the raster dataset so that nodata cells are having their true value in the resulting numpy array from the [`.read()`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.DatasetReader.read) method?

```
import rasterio

src = rasterio.open(
    input_file_path,
    mode = 'r',
    driver = 'GTiff',
    count = None,
    crs = 'EPSG:2056',
    transform = None,
    dtype = 'float32',
)

data = src.read()

data # <- print an array with 'nan' in cells with nodata.
src.nodata # <- prints -9999.0
```

I'd like an array where nodata cells equal `-9999.0`.

Comment: Why do you specify driver, count, crs, transform & dtype when reading? It's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce.  Given a raster where `src.nodata` is -9999.0 *and* actually has -9999.0 values in the dataset, reading the data as a numpy array gives -9999.0 as expected with rasterio 1.3.3.

You will however, get `nan` values if they are stored in the dataset. Specifying `dst.nodata = -9999.0` when you write the array to file will not change those `nan` values, nor will it make rasterio magically change them to `-9999.0` when you read the data.

If you have `nan`s in your data, either change them to the required `nodata` value before you write it out, or when you read it back:

```
# Before writing
data[np.isnan(data)] = dst.nodata
dst.write(data)

# Or after reading
data = src.read()
data[np.isnan(data)] = src.nodata
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from user2856, another approach is to read the data as a masked array and then fill the masked values with the nodata value.

```
with rasterio.open(input_file_path, mode="r") as src:
    data_masked = src.read(masked=True)
    nodata_value = src.nodata

data = data_masked.filled(nodata_value)
```

I highly recommend to open the file with a context manager as it ensures that the file is closed properly and is just cleaner without a 'src.close()' at the end of the function.